# Sharepoint 2010 reverse proxy

Tags: c#, iis, sharepoint-2010, url-routing

I have two sites - old and new one.
The newest is Sharepoint 2010 portal. Several part of it are under construction and when user requests site which is under construction  I need to return page from old portal.
I've found an article which describes how to implement Sharepoint 2010 reverse proxy using URL Revrite and Application Request Routing.
But URL to old site should contain a dinamically generated parameter.

Is this possible to interfere in Sharepoint or IIS working process to generate this parameter and change dynamically this URL address before it will be processed?

Answer (score 0):

HttpModule will allow you to run some codez inside HttpRequest processor, but I'm not really sure you wanna go that route...